# Tipo de dato Numérico que soporte 75 dígitos en C#

Tags: c#, tipos

El problema actual que presento es que necesito operar con un dato numérico que puede llegar a ser muy extenso el cual actualmente posee 75 digitos.

Adjunto ejemplo del numero a trabajar:

```
904625697166532776746648320380374280100293470930272690489102837043110636675
```

Pero no conozco que tipo de dato debo trabajar en lenguaje c# de .net, el largo no me admite ni "ulong" ni "decimal".

Gracias,

Comment: Se puede saber para que necesitas eso? Obvimente no hay tipo de dato numerico que soporte tal cantidad asi que solo te queda o un array de interos o un string.

Comment: No existe tal tipo de dato para poder manipular esa cantidad de dígitos en un numérico. Al igual que Einer me queda la duda del objetivo de usar un número tan grande, igual se le puede dar la vuelta por otro lado

Comment: Eso no depende del lenguaje que en este caso sería un long que es un int64 y su máximo es 18446744073709551616, así que lo que estas pidiendo es imposible por ahora, a menos que te inventes otra arquitectura de procesamiento.

Comment: Si eso está en base decimal, yo procesaría al menos en Hexadecimal.

Comment: Con los procesadores actuales puedes manejar hasta 64 bits de datos, el número máximo que puedes manejar es 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF (considerando que si el primer bit es 1 entonces se vuelve negativo) o en decimal: 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 que son "sólo" 19 dígitos, o bien si lo manejas como `UInt64` (unsigned, sin signo) es el número que mencionó @M.Gress que son "sólo" 20 dígitos (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF).

Answer (score 2):

Proyecto -> Agregar Referencia + -> System.Numerics (OK) -> Aceptar

```
BigInteger nro = 904625697166532776746648320380374280100293470930272690489102837043110636675;
```

Prueba utilizando el tipo `BigInteger` pero tal como dicen los demás creo que no soporta esa cantidad de dígitos.

Puedes probar ir concatenando y guardando resultados por parte del dígito.